# Why an error occurred when I run slmgr command in my Windows 10 Command Prompt?

Tags: command-line, bootcamp, windows, security

I downloaded a fresh copy of **Windows 10 ISO file** named `Win10_2004_English_x64.iso` from the official Microsoft website.

I installed it on my MacBook Air via **Boot Camp Assitant**.

All process was successfully completed and it is running successfully.

but...

When I run `slmgr` command on Command Prompt It shows me the following error message (screenshot attached):-

**Error Message**

```
Error 0x80041002 occurred in connecting to the local registry.
On a computer running Microsoft Windows non-core edition, run 'slui.exe
0x2a 0x80041002' to display the error text.
```

[image: slmgr command error message screenshot]

When I run `slui.exe` It opens a popup window and asks for entering product key.

I think the Apple security system prevents me from running that command (correct me if I am wrong).

How to fix this? Why I can't run `slmgr` command? (It's working perfectly with Virtual Machines like Parallels and VMware and also on other Windows Machines)

Comment: If you're trying to change the key, do as it says & run slui.exe instead This really isn't an Apple issue, it's definitely Microsoft.

Comment: You probably need to run this in an Administrator Command Prompt window. Also, other websites ([Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/volume-activation/activate-using-key-management-service-vamt) and [others](https://www.howtogeek.com/245445/how-to-use-slmgr-to-change-remove-or-extend-your-windows-license/)) show the `.vbs` extension being entered. In other words, enter `slmgr.vbs`.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried the same command on another windows machine with a fresh installation of the same version of Windows 10 and it's perfectly working but not in my case.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I ran ```slmgr``` and ```slmgr.vbs``` commands as an administrator but the output is same.